# py2neo 2.0 bind and push node errors

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, py2neo

Using Py2Neo 2.0 and Pycharm Community Edition 4

I'm trying to update a node.  First I get the node object, change a node property, bind to the database, and then push the node.  I get a slew of errors.  Here is the code.

```
user_node = Graph().find_one('USER',
                             property_key='email',
                             property_value='marnee@marnee.com')    
user_properties['mission_statement'] = 'New mission statement'
user_node.bind(uri=Graph().uri)
user_node.push()
```

The node is found, it does have a mission_statement property.  The exception seems to happen on .push().  The Graph() uri is good, too.

Below are the errors.

I had been able to do this successfully about a week ago.  I have not updated any packages recently.

The **really weird part** is that if I have a breakpoint and run this in debug mode I do not get any errors and the node is updated successfully.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marnee Dearman/PycharmProjects/AgoraDev/py2neo_2.0_tests/create_rel_int_loc.py", line 27, in <module>
    user_node.push()
  File "C:\Users\Marnee Dearman\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnvs\AgoraDev\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py", line 1519, in push
    batch.push()
  File "C:\Users\Marnee Dearman\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnvs\AgoraDev\lib\site-packages\py2neo\batch\push.py", line 73, in push
    self.graph.batch.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\Marnee Dearman\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnvs\AgoraDev\lib\site-packages\py2neo\batch\core.py", line 99, in run
    response = self.post(batch)
  File "C:\Users\Marnee Dearman\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnvs\AgoraDev\lib\site-packages\py2neo\batch\core.py", line 88, in post
    data.append(dict(job, id=i))
  File "C:\Users\Marnee Dearman\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnvs\AgoraDev\lib\site-packages\py2neo\batch\core.py", line 232, in __iter__
    yield "to", self.target.uri_string
  File "C:\Users\Marnee Dearman\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnvs\AgoraDev\lib\site-packages\py2neo\batch\core.py", line 180, in uri_string
    uri_string = self.entity.ref
  File "C:\Users\Marnee Dearman\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnvs\AgoraDev\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py", line 1421, in ref
    return "node/%s" % self._id
  File "C:\Users\Marnee Dearman\PycharmProjects\VirtualEnvs\AgoraDev\lib\site-packages\py2neo\core.py", line 1412, in _id
    self.__id = int(self.uri.path.segments[-1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Using Nigel's advice below, I got this to work.  It was a usage error on my part:

```
user_node = Graph().find_one('USER',
                             property_key='email',
                             property_value='marnee@email.com')
user_node.properties['mission_statement'] = 'New mission statement'
user_node.push()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code so I will try to clarify the correct usage of these methods.

The `bind` method is used to connect a local entity (in this case, `Node`) to a corresponding remote equivalent. You should generally never need to use this method explicitly as entities are typically bound automatically on creation or retrieval. In your case, the `find_one` method does exactly this and constructs a client-side node that is bound to a corresponding server-side node; an explicit `bind` is not required.

The second issue is with your usage of `bind`. The URI taken by this method is that of a specific remote resource. You have passed the URI of the `Graph` itself (probably `http://localhost:7474/db/data/`) instead of that of the `Node` (such as `http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/2345`). The actual error that you see is caused by py2neo attempting to strip the ID from the URI and failing.

The simple solution is to remove the `bind` call.

Comment: Oops yes that makes sense.  I actually did understand this and I am even doing it the right way in lots of other code.  That should have been obvious to me.  I took out the bind and it works without error.  Thank you so much.